# how to make a Remember me button in business-catalyst login page?

Tags: forms, adobe, business-catalyst

I am using business-catalyst  and i create a login page with remember me button but this not working for me? any idea

My code

```
            <form name="catseczoneform82513" onsubmit="return checkWholeForm82513(this)" method="post" action="https://galleryof.worldsecuresystems.com/ZoneProcess.aspx?ZoneID=-1&amp;Referrer=http%3a%2f%2fgalleryofjewels.worldsecuresystems.com&amp;OID=5463960&amp;OTYPE=1">
                <div class="form">
                <div class="item"><label for="SZUsername">Username</label><br />
                <input type="text" class="cat_textbox_small" name="Username" id="SZUsername" maxlength="255" /></div>
                <div class="item"><label for="SZPassword">Password</label><br />
                <input type="password" class="cat_textbox_small" name="Password" id="SZPassword" maxlength="255" /></div>
                <div class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" id="RememberMe" /><label for="RememberMe">Remember Me</label></div>
                <div class="item"><input type="submit" class="cat_button" value="Log in" />&nbsp;<a href="/_System/SystemPages/PasswordRetrieveRequest">Lost password?</a></div>
                </div>
                <script src="/CatalystScripts/ValidationFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            </form>
```

Comment: Can you please provide more detail as far as what "not working for me" refers to? What is the behaviour you're expecting and what is the behaviour your are experiencing?

Answer (score 2):

The form code for "Remember Me" in Business Catalyst is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" />
<label for="RememberMe">Remember Me</label>
```

Your code looks correct. It could be a browser issue. I have had the same issue and it was my browser settings not the code. The same code on my site works without issue.

Comment: This setting is reflected in the `VSV████` cookie; if `RememberMe` is set, its expiry timestamp is now + 1 year, otherwise it's now + 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `value="on"`:

```
<div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" value="on" id="RememberMe" />
    <label for="RememberMe">Remember Me</label>
</div>
```

Comment: it is not working whenever i log out my page remember me function not remember my username and password any idea

Answer (score 1):

Just reading through the answers and comments, I think perhaps the issue is around your expectation/understanding of what the *Remember Me* checkbox does.

**The purpose of the *Remember Me* checkbox is to keep the user logged in**. It sets a persistent cookie in the user's browser (browsers settings allowing) so that the next time the user visits the site (having closed their browser and/or restarted their device in the meantime) they are already logged in and have access to the secure content. The isn't a heck of a lot of info about it, but I did find [this](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/984498).

**The "Remember Me" checkbox doesn't pre-populate the *Username* and *Password* fields**. If you're logging out, I think that's your problem right there. You're effectively cancelling out the *Remember Me* functionality by doing so.

**If you're wanting pre-poulation/auto-complete functionality**, make sure that you've set the `autocomplete="on"` on the fields in question. ([Documentation here](http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/user-manual/CRM/web-forms/customizing-webforms#no-autocomplete))